# How to use DbContextFactory in ABP?

Tags: entity-framework-core, task-parallel-library, dbcontext, abp

Is there a possibility of using [DbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) and Repositories in the [ABP Framework](https://abp.io/)?

Or are there other approaches to insert rows into the database in parallel?

Comment: In parallel because of what? Slow insert?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv inserting thousands of records is slow for us. The order doesn't matter, so we can chunk them and insert them in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried `BulkCopy`? Or it is not applicable?